# What's the opposite of "by force" in this case?

Tags: phrase-request

> Since the Roman general had an unlimited power in Judea, he could have
> easily entered any synagogue with the help of his soldiers, but that
> would not endear him to the Jewish members of that synagogue.
> Therefore, he was seeking a way to be invited into that synagogue. In
> short, although he could have come by force, he yet wanted to come
> _____________ .

1. by peace
2. in peace
3. through peace
4. voluntarily
5. ?

Comment: Which answer do you think is correct?

Comment: @RonaldSole - I am not sure. "Through peace" looks as the most possible one, but maybe "voluntarily" is better.

Comment: **through peace** is not idiomatic. Neither is **by peace**. But **in peace** fits. **Voluntarily** does not fit the context.

Comment: "... the Jewish members of that synagogue." - what other members might there be?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Converted Greeks who usually didn't have any authority in a synagogue.

Comment: “Peacefully” is another word that works in this context.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey "Jewish" doesn't seem to be used to specifiy a subset of the members, but to describe a relevant quality of the members, similar to "members of that synagogue, since they're Jewish"

Comment: " Converted Greeks" - are they not 'Jewish' if they are members of a synagogue? Or am I getting a bit controversial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a negative here might be more appropriate (at least given common speech patterns).

I would recommend something like "without resorting to coercion"

> In short, although he could have come by force, he desired to come without resorting to coercion.

---

**A few free critiques**

- I would probably omit "Jewish" since synagogues are by definition Jewish.
- I would remove "an" from "an unlimited power". In English we just say someone has "power", not "a power", in the same way we would say someone "has authority" not "has an authority".
- The last sentence (the one the question is about) is redundant, and likely should be omitted.

If you still want a forced vs voluntary dichotomy I would recommend the following:

> Since the roman general had unlimited power in Judea, he could have easily entered any synagogue with the help of his soldiers, but that would not endear him to the synagogue members. Therefore, he was seeking a voluntary invitation to enter the synagogue.

You could also just go with "invitation" since the voluntary nature can be inferred from  context.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and for the critiques. "_I would probably omit "Jewish" since synagogues are by definition Jewish._" - But I didn't say "_Jewish synagogue_", I said "_Jewish members of that synagogue_", converted Greeks being the non-Jewish members.

Comment: @brilliant If they've converted, they're Jewish now.

Comment: @brilliant It's worth noting that "Jewish" is an adjective that can refer to either the religion or to the ethnicity. If someone practices Judaic faith, I would call them "Jewish" even if their parents were not ethnic Jews. (Note that this intersection is complicated; here is [one modern perspective](https://www.heyalma.com/the-problem-with-the-term-ethnic-jew/).) If are integrated into a synagogue and practice Judaic holidays, etc., you are Jewish.

Comment: @apsillers - the very idea that there is such a thing as a 'Jewish ethnicity' is a controversial one. Most geneticists say that biologically, Jews are not different from non-Jews.

Comment: "Who can become a Jew? Anyone who wishes to take on the obligations of a Jewish life can become a Jew... A non‑Jew who converts to Judaism is
Jewish for all purposes." - Leicester (UK) Progressive Synagogue. Seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Then what if I write "Hebrew members of that synagogues"? Will that be ok then?

Comment: You have failed to understand that 'the Jewish members of the synagogue' is redundant, and you only need to say 'the members of the synagogue'. A synagogue is a place of worship for Jews. Even better, "Since the Roman general had an unlimited power in Judea, he could have easily entered any synagogue with the help of his soldiers, but that would not endear him to **its members**."

Comment: @brilliant True, but don't you think the Greek converts would be offended as well?  You can make the distinction if you want, but I'm not sure it is relevant to the overall point you are trying to make. If we are talking about the Roman empire it is generally assumed the vast majority of synagogue goers are ethnically Jewish.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey In ancient Rome there absolutely were ethnic Jews, descendants of the 12 tribes of Israel.  But I do agree that Jewish can refer to both an ethnicity and a religion.  Even in biblical times there were provisions for non-ethnic Jews to become "Jewish".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  I disagree with the notion that the genetic basis of Jewish ethnicity is at all controversial.  There are several recessive genetic diseases that are characteristic problems in Jewish communities such as Tay–Sachs.  In fact, the genetic basis of the ethnicity is so strong, many Jewish communities require people get genetic testing before dating.  If you and your potential mate are not genetically compatible (carrying incompatible disease alleles) you are not allowed to date.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - "_You have failed to understand that 'the Jewish members of the synagogue' is redundant_" - I understood that. And that's why I asked you the question: "What if I write "Hebrew members of that synagogues"? Will that be ok then?" After all, there were cases when a Jewish synagogue had both Hebrew and Greek members in it.

Comment: @Cole - "_True, but don't you think the Greek converts would be offended as well?_" - Yes, I do think so. But in the passage that I quoted the Greek converts didn't hold any power in that synagogue, while that Roman general wanted to establish good relationship with those who had real power in it, and those were the Hebrew Jews.

Comment: @brilliant If you want to focus on people in power, maybe you want to reference the Rabbis (synagogue leaders) specifically then?  (this also covers the previous issue/question as only Hebrews could lead synagogues at the time)

Comment: @Cole - That's a good choice. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

*through peace* doesn't work because *peace* is rarely perceived as something spacial you can metaphorically go through. Fundamentally, *through* means *from one end to another*, and peace is more of an abstract concept/idea/state free from war and violence.

You might say

> through a peaceful settlement
>
> through a peaceful discussion/dialogue
>
> through a peaceful process (of)

*By peace* doesn't work either. At least, I couldn't find any reasonable application.

*voluntarily* doesn't fit semantically, which leaves us with *in peace* or *peacefully*. Any words synonymous with *peacefully* might work to some extent here: quietly, calmly, inoffensively, harmlessly, politely, civilly.

Answer (score 5):

I'd prefer "peaceably". "By peace" or "through peace" don't seem to work.  Peace isn't the method of gaining entry but a consequence of a method that doesn't involve force.

For me, "in peace" suggest "with the intent to be peaceful after arriving. Yet this is probably the intended answer since "come in peace" is an idiom.  And for me, "peacefully" suggests restfully or in a relaxed manner.

Peaceably works for me. It means "without force or violence"

Comment: The word that came to my mind was "peacefully", which has a very similar meaning but is a bit more common. Either would work here, but one can read about the difference at [this StackExchange question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/343070/peaceably-vs-peacefully).

Answer (score 4):

"as a guest" (or "by invitation" or "as an invited guest", except "invite" was used earlier in the paragraph so won't sound good here).

"Invited" or "guest" go together. If you're invited somewhere, you're considered to be their guest. Likewise if you're a guest, it means you've been invited. A "guest list" is people who have been invited to some event. In English "guest" has the same real meaning it probably does everywhere: you promise to be behave well and they promise to treat you well while you're there.